# Query to eliminate a row based on date value and duplicate on another row

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I would like to eliminate rows based on the following criteria
If column `WORK_DATE` has duplicate dates then I need to exclude the row based on `CHEQUE_DATE` being `23-JAN-2015`, but keep the other rows.
Primary unique key is `EMP_ID`

**Contents of the table:**

```
 EMP_ID |  WORK_DATE  | CHEQUE_DATE
------------------------------------
  12345 | 10-SEP-2014 | 23-JAN-2015
  12345 | 10-SEP-2014 | 03-OCT-2015
  32789 | 14-OCT-2014 | 23-JAN-2015
  32789 | 14-OCT-2014 | 10-OCT-2015
```

Therefore in all cases where the work date duplicates for an employee, remove the line that has the `CHEQUE_DATE` of `Jan 23, 2015`.

I suppose it can be solved using `UNION` clause.

Comment: How can the primary key be `col1`?  It has duplicates.

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the output? Also what is the logic behind specifying the cheque_date? Are you after the row with the latest cheque_date?

Comment: Gordon, yes, my apologies, rather the unique cols would be col1,col2 and col3

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your conditions into a `where` clause.  Assuming that there are no duplicate dates for the checks:

```
delete from data
    where exists (select 1
                  from data d2
                  where d2.col1 = data.col1 and d2.work_date = data.work_date and
                        d2.cheque_date <> data.cheque_date
                 ) and
          cheque_date = date '2015-01-23';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon, based on your suggestion I cam up with the following.
It was a bit more complex as there are multiple tables involved... but your direction helped.

```
SELECT
           T.EMP_GROUP_CODE  GROUP_CODE,
           E.EMPLOYEE_ID   EMP_ID,
           SUBSTR(E.SURNAME||', '||nvl(E.FIRST_NAME,' '),1,30)
                                  EMPLOYEE_NAME,
          SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(T.WORK_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),1,11) WORK_DATE,
           SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(C.CHEQUE_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),1,11) CHQ_DATE,
           L.ABBRV_NAME  LOCATION_NM,
           SUBSTR(R.SURNAME||', '||R.FIRST_NAME,1,25) REPLACEMENT_NAME,
           T.UNITS_IN_PERIOD,
           T.HOURLY_RATE,
           T.WORK_DATE  SORT_DATE FROM EC_LOCATION             L,
                  EC_PAY_PERIOD_CALENDAR  C,
                  EC_EMPLOYEE             E,
                  EC_EMPLOYEE             R,
                  EC_EMPLOYEE_TIMESHEETS  T
            WHERE L.CODE = T.LOCATION_CODE
              AND C.PAY_NUMBER = T.PAY_NUMBER
              AND C.EMP_GROUP_CODE = T.EMP_GROUP_CODE
              AND E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
              AND T.REPLACED_EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID (+)
              AND (:P_EMP_GROUP = 'ALL'
                 OR  T.EMP_GROUP_CODE = :P_EMP_GROUP)
              AND T.WORK_DATE BETWEEN to_date(:P_START_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_date(:P_END_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
              AND T.EMP_GROUP_CODE IN ('5132E','5132S','5131DE','5131DS')
              AND (EXISTS (select 1 from ec_employee_timesheets a, ec_pay_period_calendar b where a.PAY_NUMBER = b.PAY_NUMBER
                       AND a.EMP_GROUP_CODE = b.EMP_GROUP_CODE AND SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(b.CHEQUE_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),1,11) <>
    '23-JAN-2015'));
```